# Table of Contents - Animate to scroll issue & add additional padding to scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Hello I am trying to improve my table of content snippet. Its working great however i have 2 issues.

**Issue 1:** Right now its scrolling to the H Tag instantly. How can i get it to animate to the scroll position instead of "snapping" to it?

**Issue 2:** I have a sticky navigation that is about 80px height. So when the H Tag is scrolled to i would like it to leave an additional 100px space above its "scroll location" when scrolling to header tags.

Here is my code. You can run the "Full Code Snippet" Below.

```js
//Settings
window.articleWrapperId = '#article-wrapper';
window.tableWrapperId = '#article-toc';

$(document).ready(function(){
    createToC();
});

function createToC(){
    //For Each H2 in the wrapper
    $(window.articleWrapperId + ' h2').each(function(i){
        //Get it's inner HTML
        var h2title = $(this).html();
        //Remove any spaces in it
        var anchorId = h2title.replace(/\s/g, '');
        //Attach that as an id to the H2
        $(this).attr('id', anchorId);
        //Create an anchor for this
        var anch = '<a href="#' + anchorId + '">' + h2title + '</a>';
        //Append it to the Table of Contents Wrapper
        $(window.tableWrapperId).append(anch);
    });
}
```

```css
/* https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ v2.0 | 20110126 License: none (public domain)*/a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,article,aside,audio,b,big,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,center,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,mark,menu,nav,object,ol,output,p,pre,q,ruby,s,samp,section,small,span,strike,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,tt,u,ul,var,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:after,blockquote:before,q:after,q:before{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
*{box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: #666;
}
#article-wrapper{
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    float: left;
    padding: 40px;
}
#article-toc{   
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-left: 2px dashed #aaa;
    padding: 40px;
}
h2, h3{
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #333;
}
h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

p{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
a:hover{
    color: red;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #article-wrapper{
        width: 100%;
    }
    #article-toc{   
        width: 100%;
        position: inherit;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px dashed #aaa;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article-toc">
    <h3>Table Of Contents</h3>
</div>

<div id="article-wrapper">
    <h2>The First Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Second Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Third Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Fourth Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Fifth Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Sixth Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Seventh Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Eighth Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Issue #1, you can add the `scrollTop` in the `animate()` jquery function.

```js
//Settings
window.articleWrapperId = '#article-wrapper';
window.tableWrapperId = '#article-toc';

$(document).ready(function(){
    createToC();
});

function createToC(){
    //For Each H2 in the wrapper
    $(window.articleWrapperId + ' h2').each(function(i){
        //Get it's inner HTML
        var h2title = $(this).html();
        //Remove any spaces in it
        var anchorId = h2title.replace(/\s/g, '');
        //Attach that as an id to the H2
        $(this).attr('id', anchorId);
        //Create an anchor for this
        var anch = '<a href="#' + anchorId + '">' + h2title + '</a>';
        //Append it to the Table of Contents Wrapper
        $(window.tableWrapperId).append(anch);
    });
     $('a').on('click', function(e){
         e && e.preventDefault();
         var hrefLoc = $(this).attr('href');
         //var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
         //below 80 represents 80px, which is the height of the header
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(hrefLoc).offset().top - 80
          }, 300);
   });
}
```

```css
/* https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ v2.0 | 20110126 License: none (public domain)*/a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,article,aside,audio,b,big,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,center,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,mark,menu,nav,object,ol,output,p,pre,q,ruby,s,samp,section,small,span,strike,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,tt,u,ul,var,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:after,blockquote:before,q:after,q:before{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
*{box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: #666;
}
#article-wrapper{
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    float: left;
    padding: 40px;
}
#article-toc{   
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-left: 2px dashed #aaa;
    padding: 40px;
}
h2, h3{
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #333;
}
h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

p{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
a:hover{
    color: red;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #article-wrapper{
        width: 100%;
    }
    #article-toc{   
        width: 100%;
        position: inherit;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px dashed #aaa;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article-toc">
    <h3>Table Of Contents</h3>
</div>

<div id="article-wrapper">
    <h2>The First Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Second Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Third Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Fourth Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Fifth Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Sixth Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Seventh Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <h2>The Eighth Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dictumst nam turpis ipsum porta ad, wisi ut, dolor qui quam volutpat id donec, tristique convallis velit ac, at magnis nec justo. Libero dui. Sit pede tortor non massa a mollis. Vitae suspendisse lorem parturient commodo ut fringilla, ornare non, integer blandit. Vestibulum aliquet mauris, auctor suspendisse, posuere molestie id vitae tempor asperiores purus, consectetuer morbi, orci omnis mattis ultrices amet lacus.</p>
```

For Issue #2, you can calculate the height of the header (see the commented line) or give it a fixed value and subtract it to the `offset().top` value

Comment: Wow man thanks so much for the quick solution! I was trying offset top but kept getting errors when trying to apply it. I really appreciate your help here!

Now i just got to get it to ignore punctuation in the titles. Cuz i noticed some issues with the id's having apostrophes and question marks and stuff in them. 

Cheers!